# After OpenSuse update a new connection with IP 127.0.0.1 appeared in my PC

Tags: networking, opensuse, ethernet

After an update this happened. I can't disconnect this lo connection and whenever I disconnect it it automatically connects itself. I checked its IP and found out 127.0.0.1.

I don't know if this is good or bad. Should I keep it and how can I remove if it is not good for my PC?

[image]

[image]

Gave these two pictures so that it is easier to understand.

Comment: Leap or Tumbleweed?

Comment: Here are a couple of Wikipedia articles which I hope help you understand what this is about: [Localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) and [Virtual Loopback interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Virtual_loopback_interface)

Answer (score 3):

`127.0.0.1` is the special IP attributed to the [loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) (`lo`) interface, used for communication between some services on your own machine and has **no** access to anything else than the physical machine

If you ever used an address that has `localhost` in it's URL (like if you ever ran a local web server, or some programs that expose a Web UI), this is the used interface and `localhost` will resolve to `127.0.0.1`

> don't know if this is good or bad

It is definitely not malicious or anything, now, I don't think it should appear in NetworkManager, but I suggest you just leave it alone

Comment: Thank you  for your help